# hibernate using jpa and glassfish 3.0.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, persistence.xml

hello all i am using `hibernate` using `jpa` in my project and accessing dao's like new (dao name).(methdoname)...
eg. `new OrdersDao().createOrder()`
so i would like to ask you is it a good practice to use it this way..or if something else then please suggest me...i am asking this question as after few clicks for navigation in my application i am getting message of connection and application gets crashed ..
the error is like below.
WARNING: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ mypoolname ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.in``ternal.api.PoolingException: In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections.
    WARNING: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections.]

### SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active

this is my persistence.xml file...

---

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0"> 
<persistence-unit name="mypu" >
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<non-jta-data-source>myjndi</non-jta-data-source>
<properties>
<property name="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer"
value="false" />
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
<property name="show_sql" value="true" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: can you share your dataSource configuration

Comment: public class EntityMgrFactory {
 static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mypersistenceUnit"); 
 
 public static EntityManagerFactory getEmf(){
  try{
  return entityManagerFactory;
  }catch(Exception e){
   
  e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
  return null;
 }

}